# dc.js and crossfilter app to display multiple charts

Tags: javascript, template, data-visualization, d3.js

Consider the following crossfilter / dc.js app ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxEdG.png)):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Data Exploration Tool MVP</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://unpkg.com/dc@3/dc.css"/>
    <style>
      #data-count {
        margin-top: 0;
        text-align: left;
        float: none;
      }
      table {
        table-layout: fixed;
      }
      td {
        width: 1%;
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid" style="margin: 10px;">

  <div class="row">
    <h2>Data Exploration Tool</h2>
    <div class="col-md-3 well well-sm">
      <div class="dc-data-count" id="data-count">
          <span class="filter-count"></span>
           selected out of
          <span class="total-count"></span>
           points |
          <a href="javascript:dc.filterAll(); dc.renderAll();">Reset All</a><br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">

      <!-- First row of charts -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div id="chart-11" style="width:100%;">
            <div id="chart-11-title"></div>
            <div class="reset" style="visibility: hidden;">range: <span class="filter"></span>
              <a href="javascript:chart_11.filterAll();dc.redrawAll();">reset</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div id="chart-12" style="width:100%;">
            <div id="chart-12-title"></div>
            <div class="reset" style="visibility: hidden;">selected: <span class="filter"></span>
              <a href="javascript:chart_12.filterAll();dc.redrawAll();">reset</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div id="chart-13" style="width:100%;">
              <div id="chart-13-title"></div>
            <div class="reset" style="visibility: hidden;">selected: <span class="filter"></span>
              <a href="javascript:chart_13.filterAll();dc.redrawAll();">reset</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div id="chart-14" style="width:100%;">
                <div id="chart-14-title"></div>
              <div class="reset" style="visibility: hidden;">selected: <span class="filter"></span>
                <a href="javascript:chart_14.filterAll();dc.redrawAll();">reset</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Second row of chart -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div id="chart-21" style="width:100%;">
            <div id="chart-21-title"></div>
            <div class="reset" style="visibility: hidden;">selected: <span class="filter"></span>
              <a href="javascript:chart_21.filterAll();dc.redrawAll();">reset</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div id="chart-22" style="width:100%;">
            <div id="chart-22-title"></div>
            <div class="reset" style="visibility: hidden;">range: <span class="filter"></span>
              <a href="javascript:chart_22.filterAll();dc.redrawAll();">reset</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div id="chart-23"style="width:100%;">
            <div id="chart-23-title"></div>
            <div class="reset" style="visibility: hidden;">selected: <span class="filter"></span>
              <a href="javascript:chart_23.filterAll();dc.redrawAll();">reset</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div id="chart-24"style="width:100%;">
              <div id="chart-24-title"></div>
              <div class="reset" style="visibility: hidden;">selected: <span class="filter"></span>
                <a href="javascript:chart_24.filterAll();dc.redrawAll();">reset</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.9.1/d3.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crossfilter/1.3.12/crossfilter.js"></script>
<script src="http://unpkg.com/dc@3/dc.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

'use strict';

dc.config.defaultColors(d3.schemeSet1);

var 
    chart_11   = dc.barChart("#chart-11"),
    chart_12   = dc.barChart("#chart-12"),
    chart_13   = dc.barChart("#chart-13"),
    chart_21   = dc.barChart("#chart-21"),
    chart_22   = dc.barChart("#chart-22"),
    chart_23   = dc.barChart("#chart-23"),
    data_count = dc.dataCount(".dc-data-count");

d3.csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/JasonAizkalns/32ece5c815f9ac5d540c41dc0825bbab/raw/362050300ddcb99f195044c00d9f26b0d7d489ca/data.csv").then(function(data) {

var var_names = ["x", "y", "z", "a", "b", "c"];

$("#chart-11-title").append(["<h5>", var_names[0], "<br>Subtitle</h5>"].join(""));
$("#chart-12-title").append(["<h5>", var_names[1], "<br>Subtitle</h5>"].join(""));
$("#chart-13-title").append(["<h5>", var_names[2], "<br>Subtitle</h5>"].join(""));
$("#chart-21-title").append(["<h5>", var_names[3], "<br>Subtitle</h5>"].join(""));
$("#chart-22-title").append(["<h5>", var_names[4], "<br>Subtitle</h5>"].join(""));
$("#chart-23-title").append(["<h5>", var_names[5], "<br>Subtitle</h5>"].join(""));

var c11_bin = 10,
    c12_bin = 10,
    c13_bin = 500,
    c21_bin = 100,
    c22_bin = 20,
    c23_bin = 1000;


var ndx = crossfilter(data),

    chart_11_dim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return +d[var_names[0]]; }),
    chart_12_dim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return +d[var_names[1]]; }),
    chart_13_dim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return +d[var_names[2]]; }),
    chart_21_dim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return +d[var_names[3]]; }),
    chart_22_dim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return +d[var_names[4]]; }),
    chart_23_dim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return +d[var_names[5]]; }),

    chart_11_grp = chart_11_dim.group(function(d) { return Math.floor(d / c11_bin) * c11_bin }).reduceCount(),
    chart_12_grp = chart_12_dim.group(function(d) { return Math.floor(d / c12_bin) * c12_bin }).reduceCount(),
    chart_13_grp = chart_13_dim.group(function(d) { return Math.floor(d / c13_bin) * c13_bin }).reduceCount(),
    chart_21_grp = chart_21_dim.group(function(d) { return Math.floor(d / c21_bin) * c21_bin }).reduceCount(),
    chart_22_grp = chart_22_dim.group(function(d) { return Math.floor(d / c22_bin) * c22_bin }).reduceCount(),
    chart_23_grp = chart_23_dim.group(function(d) { return Math.floor(d / c23_bin) * c23_bin }).reduceCount();

var all = ndx.groupAll();

data_count.dimension(ndx)
  .group(all);

var chart_11_min = +chart_11_dim.bottom(1)[0][var_names[0]],
    chart_11_max = +chart_11_dim.top(1)[0][var_names[0]],
    chart_12_min = +chart_12_dim.bottom(1)[0][var_names[1]],
    chart_12_max = +chart_12_dim.top(1)[0][var_names[1]],
    chart_13_min = +chart_13_dim.bottom(1)[0][var_names[2]],
    chart_13_max = +chart_13_dim.top(1)[0][var_names[2]],
    chart_21_min = +chart_21_dim.bottom(1)[0][var_names[3]],
    chart_21_max = +chart_21_dim.top(1)[0][var_names[3]],
    chart_22_min = +chart_22_dim.bottom(1)[0][var_names[4]],
    chart_22_max = +chart_22_dim.top(1)[0][var_names[4]],
    chart_23_min = +chart_23_dim.bottom(1)[0][var_names[5]],
    chart_23_max = +chart_23_dim.top(1)[0][var_names[5]];

var breathing_room = 0.05;

chart_11
  .dimension(chart_11_dim)
  .group(chart_11_grp)
  .round(dc.round.floor)
  .alwaysUseRounding(true)
  .x(d3.scaleLinear().domain([chart_11_min - ((chart_11_max - chart_11_min) * breathing_room), chart_11_max + ((chart_11_max - chart_11_min) * breathing_room)]))
  .xUnits(function(start, end, xDomain) { return (end - start) / c11_bin; })
  .controlsUseVisibility(true);

chart_12
  .dimension(chart_12_dim)
  .group(chart_12_grp)
  .round(dc.round.floor)
  .alwaysUseRounding(true)
  .x(d3.scaleLinear().domain([chart_12_min - ((chart_12_max - chart_12_min) * breathing_room), chart_12_max + ((chart_12_max - chart_12_min) * breathing_room)]))
  .xUnits(function(start, end, xDomain) { return (end - start) / c12_bin; })
  .controlsUseVisibility(true);

chart_13
  .dimension(chart_13_dim)
  .group(chart_13_grp)
  .round(dc.round.floor)
  .alwaysUseRounding(true)
  .x(d3.scaleLinear().domain([chart_13_min - ((chart_13_max - chart_13_min) * breathing_room), chart_13_max + ((chart_13_max - chart_13_min) * breathing_room)]))
  .xUnits(function(start, end, xDomain) { return (end - start) / c13_bin; })
  .controlsUseVisibility(true);

chart_21
  .dimension(chart_21_dim)
  .group(chart_21_grp)
  .round(dc.round.floor)
  .alwaysUseRounding(true)
  .x(d3.scaleLinear().domain([chart_21_min - ((chart_21_max - chart_21_min) * breathing_room), chart_21_max + ((chart_21_max - chart_21_min) * breathing_room)]))
  .xUnits(function(start, end, xDomain) { return (end - start) / c21_bin; })
  .controlsUseVisibility(true);

chart_22
  .dimension(chart_22_dim)
  .group(chart_22_grp)
  .round(dc.round.floor)
  .alwaysUseRounding(true)
  .x(d3.scaleLinear().domain([chart_22_min - ((chart_22_max - chart_22_min) * breathing_room), chart_22_max + ((chart_22_max - chart_22_min) * breathing_room)]))
  .xUnits(function(start, end, xDomain) { return (end - start) / c22_bin; })
  .controlsUseVisibility(true);

chart_23
  .dimension(chart_23_dim)
  .group(chart_23_grp)
  .round(dc.round.floor)
  .alwaysUseRounding(true)
  .x(d3.scaleLinear().domain([chart_23_min - ((chart_23_max - chart_23_min) * breathing_room), chart_23_max + ((chart_23_max - chart_23_min) * breathing_room)]))
  .xUnits(function(start, end, xDomain) { return (end - start) / c23_bin; })
  .controlsUseVisibility(true);

dc.renderAll();

});

</script>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am specifically looking for advice on how to cleanup and better scale the javascript / dc.js code:

1. How to make the `chart_11`, `chart_12`, ..., `chart_23` variables dynamically?
2. Is there a way to automatically calculate natural bin sizes (e.g. `c11_bin`, `c12_bin`, ..., `c23_bin`?
3. Better ways of setting `.x()` and `.xUnits` for each `dc.js` chart object -- the code is not very DRY.

Any other improvements / suggestions for making this code easier to scale and maintain.

Comment: do you have control over the HTML?

Comment: @ohmygoodness yes, I have control over the HTML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the Computer Science 101 answer: put the parameters that change between charts into an array, and then loop over that array.

I want to include your code and data as a dc.js example (if you will permit it?) so I started porting it to the standard format used by those examples.

The full example is here:
https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/compare-unfiltered-example/web/examples/compare-unfiltered.html

I started from my fork of your fiddle, which answers the SO question [Display original (conditional) brushed unbrushed crossfilter bars with dc.js with different colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55066391/display-original-conditional-brushed-unbrushed-crossfilter-bars-with-dc-js-wit)

You can look through the history to see all the changes from that point, but the big idea is just to put all the chart specifications into an array:

```
  var chart_specs = [
      {
          variable: 'x',
          selector: '#chart-11',
          resolution: 10
      },
      {
          variable: 'y',
          selector: '#chart-12',
          resolution: 10
      },
      {
          variable: 'z',
          selector: '#chart-13',
          resolution: 500
      },
      {
          variable: 'a',
          selector: '#chart-21',
          resolution: 100
      },
      {
          variable: 'b',
          selector: '#chart-22',
          resolution: 20
      },
      {
          variable: 'c',
          selector: '#chart-23',
          resolution: 1000
      }
  ];
```

The three things we need to know about a chart are:

- what field or variable in the data to look at
- the CSS selector of the div to put the chart in
- what resolution to bin the data in this chart

You also had unique selectors for the chart titles, but those were redundant, so I removed them.

Let's walk through the rest of the code.

#### Cleaning the data

It's more efficient to convert all the strings to numbers before giving the data to crossfilter:

```
  data.forEach(function(d) {
      chart_specs.forEach(function(spec) {
          d[spec.variable] = +d[spec.variable];
      });
  });
```

This is the first of many places where you'll see `chart_specs.forEach()`. That's the essence of the "CS 101" answer!

#### Creating the charts

Here's it's `chart_specs.map()` but the same idea:

```
  var charts = chart_specs.map(function(spec) {
      return dc.compositeChart(spec.selector);
  });
```

We'll get an array of charts back.

#### Initializing the charts

It's just one big loop over all the chart specs:

```
  chart_specs.forEach(function(spec, i) {
```

#### Title each chart

```
      d3.select(spec.selector).select('h5.chart-title').text(spec.variable);
```

For simplicity I changed the `div`s to `h5`s and gave them the class `chart-title`. Now we can change the titles with a simple generic D3 call. Otherwise it's the same idea as your old jQuery calls.

#### Create the dimension and group for each chart

We'll read `spec.variable` and `spec.resolution` in order to create appropriate dimensions and groups. We'll also make a static copy of the group data

```
      var dim = cf.dimension(function(d) { return d[spec.variable]; }),
          group = dim.group(function(d) {
              return Math.floor(d / spec.resolution) * spec.resolution;
          }).reduceCount(),
          static_group = static_copy_group(group);
```

#### Hiding the red bars if no filters are active

See [the original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55066391/display-original-conditional-brushed-unbrushed-crossfilter-bars-with-dc-js-wit) for the purpose of this code.

```
      charts[i].on('pretransition', function(chart) {
          var any_filters = charts.some(chart => chart.filters().length);
          chart.select('.sub._1')
              .attr('visibility', any_filters ? 'visible' : 'hidden')
      });
```

The only interesting here is using `charts[i]`. [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) supplies us not just the current item but the index, which we can use to access the chart in the charts array.

#### Finish the initialization

Same idea with all of the rest of the code. We just look at `spec.variable` and `spec.resolution` instead of having special variables for every chart and every value.

```
      charts[i]
          .compose([
              dc.barChart(charts[i])
                  .dimension(dim)
                  .group(static_group)
                  .controlsUseVisibility(true),
              dc.barChart(charts[i])
                  .dimension(dim)
                  .group(group)
                  .colors('red')
                  .controlsUseVisibility(true)
                  .brushOn(false)
          ]);

      var min = dim.bottom(1)[0][spec.variable],
          max = dim.top(1)[0][spec.variable];

      charts[i]
          .dimension(dim)
          .group(group)
          .round(dc.round.floor)
          .x(d3.scaleLinear().domain([min - ((max - min) * breathing_room), max + ((max - min) * breathing_room)]))
          .xUnits(function(start, end, xDomain) { return (end - start) / spec.resolution; })
          .controlsUseVisibility(true);
```

Please let me know if I can publish this example and data. It will be useful to a lot of people! (I have no idea if this data is publishable - looks suitably anonymous, hopefully...)

Comment: this is fantastic! Yes, this data is totally random / fake -- just wanted some variety. I agree, this is a great example...get it posted to the dc.js page!